# facet_wrap: place strips at the top of each category on the Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, strip, facet-wrap

I have the following `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(ORDER = c(1,2,3,4),
                 NAME_LABEL = c("COMPANY1", "COMPANY2", "COMPANY3", "COMPANY4"),
                 LABEL = c("ICT hardware", "Software", "Automobiles", "Travel"),
                 RD_PC = c(60, 50, 30, -10),
                 COLOR = c("POS", "POS", "POS", "NEG"))
```

and I produced the following plot:

```
col_fig5 <- c("#6B89BC", "#A4C76D")


test <- ggplot(df, aes(x = forcats::fct_rev(reorder(NAME_LABEL, ORDER, sum)), group = LABEL, fill = COLOR)) +
  
  geom_col(aes(y = RD_PC, fill = COLOR), width = 0.85) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_fig5) +
  ylim(c(-55, 95)) +
  
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ LABEL, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "left", as.table=TRUE) +
  
  labs(
    y = "Percentage change",
    x = "",
    fill = "",
    color = "",
    caption = ""
  ) +
  
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 4),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey85", size=0.1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour="grey85", size=0.1),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="grey85", size=0.1),
        
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5,  hjust=1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=8, vjust=0.5, hjust=1),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=0),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=8),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size=0.4),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        
        plot.caption = element_text(size=6, hjust=0),
        legend.position = "none")
```

However, since I have many companies, I would like to place the strips on the top of each category (`LABEL`) on the Y axis (see below). Is it possible? I have tried many variations of `strip.position` and `strip.` in `theme()`, but none of them seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `angle` argument of `strip.text.y.left = element_text()` to `0`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = forcats::fct_rev(reorder(NAME_LABEL, ORDER, sum)), 
               group = LABEL, fill = COLOR)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = RD_PC, fill = COLOR), width = 0.85) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_fig5) +
  ylim(c(-55, 95)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ LABEL, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", 
             strip.position = "left", as.table = TRUE) +
  labs(y = "Percentage change", x = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0, 
                                    vjust = 1, size = 8, angle = 0),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey85", size=0.1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour="grey85", size=0.1),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="grey85", size=0.1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5,  hjust=1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=8, vjust=0.5, hjust=1),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=0),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=8),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size=0.4),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        plot.caption = element_text(size=6, hjust=0),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't work with many companies. How to move the company names closer to the grid?

Comment: The problem is that the facet strips take up space, and are drawn on a different part of the underlying `gtable` to the axis labels. You can't have facet strips directly above the axis labels - they are already as close together as they can be. You could try nested facets with a blank y axis, or text annotations, or richtext strips to try to get that kind of effect. Personally, I quite like the look of adding in `strip.placement = 'outside'` to your `theme` here.